# How to get an audio file to play?

Tags: java, audio, javasound

I am having trouble getting an audio file to play in my snakes and ladders game. It should play when a player falls down a snake.

```
import sun.audio.AudioData;
import sun.audio.AudioPlayer;
import sun.audio.AudioStream;
import sun.audio.ContinuousAudioDataStream;


public void playFallingSound()
    {
        AudioPlayer MGP = AudioPlayer.player;
        AudioStream BGM;
        AudioData MD;
        ContinuousAudioDataStream loop = null;

        try{
        BGM = new AudioStream (new FileInputStream("PacMan.wav"));
        MD = BGM.getData();
        loop= new ContinuousAudioDataStream (MD);
        } catch (IOException error) {System.out.println("Error playing falling sound");}
        MGP.start(loop);
    }
```

Comment: You should tag a language when you show code. I've added the `java` tag for you.

Comment: Don't use 'sun.audio' classes they are not part of the public API. Look at the [info for the javasound tag](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javasound/info) for lots of Java sound info

Comment: I want to echo greg-449. I looked in the Java 7 API index and none of the sun audio objects are listed. Stick with javax.sound.sampled library as this remains fully supported. Tutorial is here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/sampled-overview.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this function:

```
public static synchronized void playSound(final String url) {
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                  public void run() {
                    try {
                      Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
                      AudioInputStream inputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(ChatClient.class.getResourceAsStream("/resources/" + url));
                      clip.open(inputStream);
                      clip.start();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                      System.err.println(e.getMessage());
                    }
                  }
                }).start();
              }
```